# Testing `img.onLoad`/`img.onError` using Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Out team ran into a scenario this afternoon when writing a React Testing Library (RTL) test with Jest for our `<Avatar />` component. Specifically, we wanted to test that the `<img />` tag was removed from the DOM when it fails to load (`onError` is triggered) to match the expected final view of component. For some reason, using `fireEvent` on the `<img />` DOM Element was not immediately obvious to us and we didn't find this explicit solution online so we wanted share. As you can imagine, this will work for other events such as `onLoad` as well. [More about RTL Events](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events).

```
it('should render with only initials when avatar image is NOT found', async() => {
  const { container } = render(<Avatar {...defaultMocks} />);
  const avatarImg = container.querySelector('img');

  expect(avatarImg).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent(avatarImg, new Event('error'));

  expect(avatarImg).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

get the image using testId or role then use fireEvent to call `onLoad` or `OnError` functions respectively

```
const image = getByRole('img')

fireEvent.load(image);
```

for onError

```
fireEvent.error(image)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Explanation

- `<Avatar />` is rendered with default props, and in our case, contains an `<img />` tag pointing to an optional profile image endpoint for the user.
- We then use `fireEvent` on that DOM element, triggering the `onError` function that was bound at `render` time mocking a failed/`404` case where a user avatar was not set.
- Finally we can now expect the `<img />` was removed based on the logic within `<Avatar />`