# Mocking browser download functionality

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, browser-testing, react-testing

I have a React component which internally creates a `script` DOM element. There is a bunch of logic around handling `onload` and `onerror` events of this script. The `onload` and `onerror` handlers are internal to the component, and I can't pass them via props.

I would like to write some Jest tests for this code, but not sure how to mock the browser download functionality. I'd like to mock script download error, parsing error, and download/parsing success (without any network calls). Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: try with approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481331/testing-img-onload-img-onerror-using-jest-and-react-testing-library

Comment: as for "download/parsing success" - what's the purpose here? I mean, is there a possibility then triggering `onLoad`(or at least, _not_ triggering `onError`) would lead to different results whether parsing succeeds/fails?